# Django change password issue, super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, django, passwords

i'm having some trouble with my changepassword form, it continues to give me the same error:  super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

this is my form:

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
    current_password = forms.CharField(label=u'Current Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    new_password = forms.CharField(label=u'New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    retyped_password = forms.CharField(label=u'Retype New Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    def __init__(self, data=None, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(UserProfileEditForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)

    def clean_current_password(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        current_password = cleaned_data.get('current_password', '')

        if not self.user.check_password(current_password):
            raise ValidationError('Wrong current password.')

        return current_password

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        new_password = cleaned_data.get('new_password', '')
        retyped_password = cleaned_data.get('retyped_password', '')

        if len(new_password) == 0 or len(retyped_password) == 0:
            raise ValidationError('Blank password fields.')

        if new_password != retyped_password:
            raise ValidationError('New password and retyped password do not match.')

        return cleaned_data

    def save(self):
        self.user.set_password(new_password)
        return self.user
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
super(UserProfileEditForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
```

It should be

```
super(PasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
```

It is probably a copy-paste issue, when you were copying from the other form.

Some more [context here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: Thank you, i've one more little problem with this...non the form it's ok but when i call the save function it says the global new_passord it's not deifined

Comment: You need to do `new_password = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password')`